# Does forward filtering result in OLS estimate for each time point?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, least-squares, kalman-filter

I'm learning about dynamic linear models and was trying to think about the relationship between GLS and forward filtering (Kalman filtering where the state is the vector of parameters). Here's my model:
\begin{align}
y_t &= \mathbf{F}'_t\boldsymbol{\theta} + \epsilon_t, \qquad \epsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, v)
\end{align}
Assuming I start with a noninformative prior on $\boldsymbol{\theta}_1$, if I perform forward filtering on a time series, will the state estimate of $\boldsymbol{\theta}_t$ I get for each time equal the OLS estimate I get had I seen data up to that point beforehand? Furthermore, if $v$ is time-varying (i.e. $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, v_t)$), will the state estimate for each time equal the GLS estimate had I known all the variances up to that point?

Comment: Hmm... okay, I just realized this wouldn't make any sense if $\boldsymbol{\theta}_t$ has an AR model, since forward filtering would try to adapt the state to new observations. On the other hand, OLS or GLS would simply return a state that minimizes residuals over all the observed data. Rather than considering the AR model for $\boldsymbol{\theta}_t$, let's say $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is static. Would the answers to my above questions be "yes" then?

Comment: Please edit your original question to reflect your new question, including rewriting the state equation so that it's static, then simplifying in the obvious way, so that the question and (any subsequent) answer correspond even if the comment were deleted.

Comment: is $y_t$ a scalar or a vector?

Comment: @Glen_b, okay, done! $y_t$ is a scalar.

Comment: Since $\epsilon$ and hence $y$ must now be independent over time (in the first part of the question), consider writing the corresponding equations for the entire vector of $y$s at once - i.e. put the whole thing in matrix form. Look familiar? However, note that as it stands, in the usual state space model, $v$ is specified not estimated. That can be dealt with, but you should be clear about such issues. Note also that since you have a noninformative prior on $\theta$ (presumably flat), you'd need to [modify the KF algorithm](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176349739) to deal with that

Comment: With your original AR issue in the comments, notice that if you condition on the first p observations (let's be frequentists for a moment, though you should be able to carry the insight across), an AR model reduces to a GLS model.